# How to change IEnumerable Visualizer culture info?

Tags: c#, double, cultureinfo

I have a array of numbers, which some of them are double.

when I debug the program, the decimal seperator is dot(.)

but in visual studion IEnumerable Visualizer the seperator is comma(,)

How to change it to dot back?

because I need to export it to csv and I don't want it to be with comma seperator.

**dot seperated below**

[image]

**comma seperated below**

[image]